# EFS - Find out what's encrypted

Tags: windows-vista, backup, certificate, efs

Since a few days when I start Windows Vista i get a Popup from "Encrypting File System" (coming from process efsui.exe) asking me to backup the certificate and key.

I don't know what i did to get this message (The last SW i did install was google desktop).

Now i'm wondering what directories or file are encrypted with EFS.
Is there a way to found out?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trying using this batch file :

```
@echo off
cls

:: Set the varibles - Use Quotes "" if there are spaces in the source or log path
set log_path=C:\EFS_Find

:: Find Encrypted Files
cipher /s C:\ | findstr "^.E" >> %log_path%\found.txt && echo:Encrypted files found"

:: Find Hidden Files
attrib /s C:\ 2>nul | findstr "^....H" >> %log_path%\found.txt && echo:Hidden files found"  

pause
```

This batch file will scan your C:\ drive for all EFS encrypted files (and also hidden files), echo on the screen every time it finds one, and record all instances of encrypted files found into **C:\EFS_Find\found.txt**.

For a command-line approach to finding just encrypted files, you can type in the command-line :

> cipher /s:C:\ | findstr "^.E" >> C:\efs_found.txt && echo:Encrypted files found"

This will search your entire C:\ drive for encrypted files, and dump it into **C:\efs_found.txt**.

Modified from the solution found [here](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=526).

To disable EFS on your Vista system, I refer you to the link here :

[How to Disable or Enabled EFS Encryption in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/102501-encryption-disable-enable.html)

Comment: The command listed here is incorrect (at least in win7). It should be: >cipher /s:C:\ /h | findstr "^.E" >> C:\efs_found.txt && echo:"Encrypted files found" Notice the colon after the /s.

Answer (score 3):

gsharp is correct, the syntax to display all EFS encrypted files on drive C: is

```
cipher /s:c:\ |findstr "^E"
```

Pay attention to the pipe character, which is usually found on the <kbd>\</kbd> key.  The findstr command `^E` looks for the E at the beginning of the line.  Also pay attention that the `/s` has a colon after it and the drive letter, all with no spaces.

The downside is only the filenames are returned, there is no directory structure provided.

Answer (score 0):

For Win7 users:
I just had the same problem, (someone sent me a zip file prepared on a mac, that for some reason encrypted itself on decompression), and I started to get the EFS Key backup prompt.

```
cipher /s:c:\ |findstr "^E"
```

and its variants returned no information.

however I was able to find the encrypted directories with:

```
cipher /u
```