# Backup EFS encryption key generated, but no encrypted files? Track what caused the key creation

Tags: encryption, certificate, efs

In [I started getting a weird message "Encrypting file system - Back up your file encryption key"](https://superuser.com/q/151317/68747) a user experiences a prompt that I also experienced yesterday for the first time.

Now the question: what causes the prompt if `cipher /u /n` (as admin) doesn't find any encrypted files? I.e. what caused a key to be generated in the first place? Is there a way to track that down? (also see [EFS - Find out what's encrypted](https://superuser.com/q/37896/68747))

[image]

NB: I am *not* interested in why I get the EFS prompt, but rather what causes the key to be generated, if no encrypted files seem to exist on the system and I haven't used EFS consciously myself.